# Flash/Flex/Actionscript for Undergraduate Thesis

Tags: java, php, actionscript

I am looking for a good project proposal for my undergraduate thesis subject. Our teacher assigned us two proposals to choose. Language Emulator and Interactive Image Retrieval. Both are found on www.1000projects.org. The bad thing here is that I have almost no knowledge in Java. I am confident in developing my project using Actionscript so I have these problems:

1.) A good project proposal using Actionscript (not a game). My teacher want us to develop something that uses algorithm and data manipulation.

2.) If I choose Interactive Image Retrieval ( I cant find a good actionscript-drived example),  will it be possible using Actionscript as a tool for development?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actionscript itself is a fully capable programming language. You can do data manipulation, language emulation and interactive image retrieval with it like you would with any other language.

I personally find actionscript much more rapid than java anyway.

I'm not saying you **should** choose actionscript but I can guarentee that you **can** .

EDIT:
Also, since in actionscript functions are first class objects giving it some functional abilities , building a language emulator is actually probably easier than in java since you can pretty much directly translate the language rules into code.

(I'm assuming you mean something that parses a programming language)

Comment: Yeah! your post helps me use actionscript as my tool. I am definitely going to use actionscript. The problem is that I dont like interactive image retrieval. It does not get my interest. Could you suggest me some?

Comment: it does not have to be.. just give me some good proposal and Im gonna make an abstract to that and pass for approval.

Comment: If you're already dealing with flash then anything that relates to animation might be good, what about using flash's built in drawing functions to write your own drawing program? (something along the lines of this: http://www.newgrounds.com/portal/view/256289 , and maybe add animation capabilities? or creating more complex shapes? maybe rotating? This will require you to learn some math (nothing too hard to grasp though like how to rotate stuff in space using trigonometry, how to scale stuff, and if you do it using matrices it's probably a good lesson too)

Comment: Wow, nice app. Im gonna study this one too.. maybe tomorrow I am gonna decide what to take. Any more suggestions? Thanks btw,